# Updating a table in bigquery using DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to update a table in bigquery using DBT. The below command executes in bigquery;

```
Update {{ ref('my_table') }}
SET variable = 'value'
WHERE lower(variable) LIKE '%XX%' or lower(variable) like '%YY%'
```

However when I run it in DBT I get the following error

```
Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LIMIT at [4:1]
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unintuitive at first I know but with dbt, [every model is a select statement](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models).

You should instead think of doing something like:

```
with cte as (
     select * from {{ ref('my_table') }}
     where <criteria>
)
 select col1,
        col2,
        'value' as col3
 from cte
```

Or possibly even simpler:

```
SELECT 
  'value' as variable
FROM {{ ref('my_table') }}
WHERE lower(variable) LIKE '%XX%' or lower(variable) like '%YY%'
```

Simply because during the `dbt run` cycle, the new values will be materialized into the new model.

However, if you are looking for ways to clean underlying tables in a DRY way, I'd highly recommend this thread [Modeling SQL Update Statements](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/modeling-sql-update-statements/1167/6) from the dbt discourse for some patterns on managing statements which handle specific value cleaning. Example from Kyle Ries:

```
{% set mappings = {'something': 'boo', 'something-else': 'boo-else'} %}

with source as (
        select * from {{ ref(‘stg_foobar’) }}
),

final as ( 

        select
            case
              {% for old, new in mappings %}
                when other_column like ‘{{old}}’ then ‘{{new}}’
              {% endfor %}
            end as column_name
        from
            source

)

select * from final
```

Comment: The first method worked thanks very much, great idea